# Where to put the ORDER BY in this union statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I've got this union statement that seems to be working:

```
SELECT q.id, q.hits, q.type, q.title, q.date, q.author, q.wfurl
FROM (SELECT id AS id, hits AS hits, type AS type, title AS title, date AS date, author AS author, wfurl AS wfurl, status AS status
FROM articles WHERE status = 1
UNION SELECT id, hits, type, title, published, author_id, url, status
FROM new_articles WHERE status = 1) AS q
GROUP BY q.id
```

And i'm trying to order the whole thing by the type so `ORDER BY type` but wherever I put it in seems to throw an error. I've put it up on the first line, after the AS and inside the two selects with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `order by` would go after the `group by`:

```
SELECT q.id, q.hits, q.type, q.title, q.date, q.author, q.wfurl
FROM ((SELECT id AS id, hits AS hits, type AS type, title AS title, date AS date, author AS author, wfurl AS wfurl, status AS status
       FROM articles
       WHERE status = 1
      ) UNION
      (SELECT id, hits, type, title, published, author_id, url, status
       FROM new_articles 
       WHERE status = 1
      )) q
GROUP BY q.id
ORDER BY type;
```

If you know that the two tables have no duplicates, then you should use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.  `UNION` incurs overhead by removing duplicates.  It is also redundant to assign a table alias that is the same as the name, so `hits as hits` is unnecessary (and so on).

EDIT:

If you want an efficient query, the following is probably faster and probably does what you want:

```
select a.*
from articles a
where status = 1
union all
select na.*
from new_articles na
where status = 1 and
      not exists (select 1 from articles a where a.id = na.id)
order by type;
```

This eliminates the overhead for the `union`.  If an `id` is present in both tables, it takes the value from the first one (you can reverse the order of the logic to get the values from the second).  The only real overhead is the `order by` at the end, whereas your version has overhead for the `union`, `group by`, and `order by`.

Comment: uhh I was trying ORDER BY q.type down there, thanks :p

Comment: Would it be better to stick to individual unions if you only want a few columns? These tables im selecting from have quite a lot of stuff in them this is just a few columns